# Redirect a POST request to another server

Tags: apache, post, proxy, iis-6

On a windows server running IIS6, I need to intercept a POST request to instead have it make the same POST request to another domain (including the body of the request).

What I think I need is a proxy server.

What I have tried:

- In IIS setup an HTTP Redirect but when it does the redirect, it's a GET request to the other server and that's not useful (as I lose the body and it's not a POST request)
- Installed Apache on the server that received the initial POST request. But that doesn't seem to work as it installs for ports 80 or 8080 and IIS is already using both of those.

  ```
  (OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
  ```

  Wondering if installing Apache was the wrong way to go.

Is it possible to do this in IIS? Or should I continue the Apache route?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can't you make the post to the right domain to begin with, thereby avoiding the need to intercept/redirect? What code language are you using?

Comment: I technically could, but I'd do that as a last resort. I'm not supposed to be modify the code